# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' Как исправить?

Tags: python

```
site = urllib.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT-iogyNhgE').read()
m = re.findall('<meta property="og:image" content=(.*)>', site)
urllib.urlretrieve(m, "picture.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной `m` массив вхождений шаблона `<meta property="og:image" content=(.*)>` в строку `site`, а `urlretrieve` ожидает строку.

```
import urllib
import re

site = urllib.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT-iogyNhgE').read()
m = re.findall('<meta property="og:image" content=(.*)>', site)
if m:
    url = m[0][1:-1]
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, "picture.png")
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!